# trying to display first and second form at second step

Tags: html, vue.js

Here I have written a code for multistep form and every thing is working fine here. But here while we are at first step and if we click on next button then next step form will display so here I want to show first step form along with next step form. That means while we click next button from first step then next step should be with first form and second form

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
  <div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <p>
    <legend for="name">Your Name:</legend>
    <input id="name" name="name" v-model="registration.name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="email">Your Email:</legend>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" v-model="registration.email">
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
    
  </div>

  <div v-if="step === 2">
    <h1>Step Two</h1>
    <p>
    <legend for="street">Your Street:</legend>
    <input id="street" name="street" v-model="registration.street">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="city">Your City:</legend>
    <input id="city" name="city" v-model="registration.city">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="state">Your State:</legend>
    <input id="state" name="state" v-model="registration.state">
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

  </div>

  <div v-if="step === 3">
    <h1>Step Three</h1>
    
    <p>
    <legend for="numtickets">Number of Tickets:</legend>
    <input id="numtickets" name="numtickets" type="number" v-model="registration.numtickets">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="shirtsize">Shirt Size:</legend>
    <select id="shirtsize" name="shirtsize" v-model="registration.shirtsize">
      <option value="S">Small</option>
      <option value="M">Medium</option>
      <option value="L">Large</option>
      <option value="XL">X-Large</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="submit()">Save</button>
    
  </div>
  </form>
```

**vue.js**

```
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
    return {
      step:1,
      registration:{
        name:null,
        email:null,
        street:null,
        city:null,
        state:null,
        numtickets:0,
        shirtsize:'XL'
      }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
    submit() {
      alert('Submit to blah and show blah and etc.');      
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `step` is incremented on each `next()` call, you could change the conditional rendering to render when the step is *at least* some index:

```html
<div v-if="step >= 1">...</div>
<div v-if="step >= 2">...</div>
<div v-if="step >= 3">...</div>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wvoxdwR)